# Integer solutions to a polynomial $f(x,y)$

Tags: diophantine-equations, mathematica

How can I find the integer solutions of a polynomial $f(x,y)$ such that 
$a<|x|,|y|<A$
using Mathematica?

Comment: This is not a mathematics question. Try posting this question on [this forum](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It would be better to specify whether the polynomial has integer coefficients if known.